# How to count objects inside object (without count var index)

Tags: mongodb

I have the following model stored in mongodb:

```
{
    "_id": (MongoId)
    "user": "X",
    "field-name-1":{
        "obj-1": 12345,
        "obj-2": 54321,
        "obj-3": 67890,
        (...)
    },
    "field-name-2:{
        "obj-1": {"foo":"bar", "bar":"foo"},
        "obj-2": {"foo":"bar2", "bar":"foo2"},
        (...)
    }
}
```

How do I find the ocurrences that contains more than 5 objects inside the "field-name-1"? Is it the same for "field-name-2"?

I can't use a variable to count the amount of objects because I upsert values inside the "field-name-1"/"field-name-2" constantly.

Thanks.

---

Already tried (without success):

```
db.summoners.find({$where: "this.['field-name-1'].length > 5"})
db.summoners.find({$where: "['field-name-1'].length > 5"})
```

Comment: Seems that this is an array disguised as an object. But even arrays don't (yet) support range queries on their `$size`. So, without fetching the objects, there's not much you can do, I'm afraid.

Comment: What about fixed size? I have plans to run them at least twice daily, so it wouldn't ever pass a given size.

Comment: You can query for arrays of a certain `$size`, yes.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev But with arrays you can use aggregation framework though. With objects maybe map/reduce is the only way. It's quite slow however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$where** should be qualified in this case:

```
function findMyDocument(key, value) {
    var f = this[key];
    if (typeof f != "object" || typeof value != "number") {
        return false;
    }
    var count = 0;
    for (var x in f) {
        if (++count > value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// store above function to database for invoking
db.system.js.insert({_id:"findMyDocument", value: findMyDocument});

// apply here
db.summoners.find({$where: "findMyDocument.call(this, 'field-name-1', 5);"});
db.summoners.find({$where: "findMyDocument.call(this, 'field-name-2', 5);"});
```